How does the common 4 thread example for demonstrating sequential consistency work on a system with cache coherence?
Deciding to refresh my understanding of acquire/release vs sequential consistency, I came across this common example (taken from here, but this is similar):
T1: x = 1;
T2: y = 1;
T3: if( x == 1 && y == 0 ) print( “x first” );
T4: if( y == 1 && x == 0 ) print( “y first” );

The claim is that memory_order_seq_cst is needed to prevent both messages from printing, that memory_order_acquire reads and memory_order_release writes aren't enough.
But if the system has coherent cache, how could both messages print with acquire/release? In fact, I believe that the writes can even be relaxed because it wouldn't do anything and we don't need to synchronize the writes anyway. Also, only the first read on each thread needs to be acquire to ensure that T3 reads x before y and T4 reads y before x.
With that setup, for both messages to print, T3 would need to somehow see x being written and then afterwards read y untouched, and T4 should see y written and after that read x untouched. This can happen only if the cache gives a thread a value which is older than the value it previously gave another thread, which shouldn't be possible with a coherent cache.
TLDR: Am I right in assuming that this is a bad example for sequential consistency if we assume there's cache coherence? And I've read multiple times that all CPUs handle cache coherence in hardware and that's not something to worry about.

As a side note, I find this simple demonstration from here much more convincing and easy to understand. The four-thread example just seems to make atomics mystical, and they're difficult enough already. As a bonus, cache coherence can't save you here.
T1: x = 1; if( y == 0 ) print( “x first” );
T2: y = 1; if( x == 0 ) print( “y first” );


You're correct that if the only mechanism for threads to see values from other threads is a coherent cache (which doesn't reorder things, otherwise it couldn't even support acq / rel without non-local barriers), then IRIW reordering is impossible.  As I explain in the linked duplicate, the key is a side-channel for some cores to see stores from some other cores before they become globally visible by committing to cache.  (SMT store-forwarding between logical cores.)

And yes, the stores might as well be relaxed.  The loads need to be at least acquire to rule out LoadLoad reordering vs. actual disagreement on order of the stores (IRIW reordering).

@PeterCordes Thanks. Obviously I'm bad at searching because I couldn't find the duplicate myself. Onto the answers there.

If you don't know the keyword "IRIW", it's non-trivial.  There are also multiple questions about it, and only the one I answered has an answer about the HW mechanisms.  So I knew exactly where to find what I wrote before, but it would be a lot less easy for someone who doesn't know the answer.
